How can I use a single Telethon session for multiple scripts?
I have a JSON format Telethon session. I can use it in one script without any problems, in the second if I try to use it at the same time, Telethon will output

database is locked

I tried to fix this by copying the session, and when copying directly, both scripts will run, but the problem is that if I try to disable one of the client.disconnect() sessions, the second session will also be disconnected
And this is a problem for me, because the first session does a simple one-time job, so it has to start and shut down. And the second session processes incoming messages, i.e. the event handler is connected
And after the first script completes, the event handler simply stops responding without any errors.
What should I do? How can I use one session for multiple scripts? Maybe I'm just copying something wrong?
I try to copy the session and it closes along with the first session

Telegram isn't designed for using the same session multiple times. Login to the same account under a new session instead.

You can try to use StringSession to avoid using telethon session database. After getting session string you can do as following:
async with TelegramClient(StringSession('<your_session>'), api_id, api_hash) as client:
    await execute_some_script(client)

I managed to simultaneously get list of dialogs using two different Telethon client with the same session string.
If it doesn't work, then there is no way to use the same session with Telethon (or in Telegram at all).
Telethon docs claims that telegram invalidates the session if it was used from different IPs at the same time (see AuthKeyDuplicatedError), so be careful.
